# How to install 8139 Realtek drivers in RHEL5.0? 

Tags: linux, drivers, installation

How do I install the 8139 Realtek drivers in RHEL 5.0?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this link useful:

http://faizsulaiman.com/install-nic-driver-realtek-rtl8139810x-on-linux/

It runs you through downloading the driver, compiling and installing it, and configuring and testing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have any Ethernet configured.

```
# dmesg | grep eth
# dmesg | grep 8139
```

and see whether the kernel has detected your card. Finally,

```
# lsmod | grep 8139
```

will show whether the 8139 driver is loaded.